# Convert text grid to nested dictionary in python

Tags: python

Imagine a grid in a text file like this:

```
  A  B  C
A 0  1  2
B 3  0  5
C 6  7  0
```

What would be the nicest way to convert this into a dictionary in python like the following:

```
{
  'A': {'A': 0, 'B':3, 'C':6},
  'B': {'A': 1, 'B':0, 'C':7},
  'B': {'A': 2, 'B':5, 'C':0}
}
```

So I can access cells with:

```
matrix['A']['B'] # 3
```

I currently do have some very rough code (please don't judge me too harshly):

```
matrix = {}
f = open(filepath, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
keys = lines[0].split()

for key in keys:
    matrix[key] = {}

for line in lines[1:]:
    chars = line.split()
    key_a = chars[0]
    for i, c in enumerate(chars[1:]):
        key_b = keys[i-1]
        matrix[key_a][key_b] = int(c)

print matrix

# Outputs {'A': {'A': 1, 'C': 0, 'B': 2}, 'C': {'A': 7, 'C': 6, 'B': 0}, 'B': {'A': 0, 'C': 3, 'B': 5}}
```

Whilst this isn't wrong, I've spent a long time away from python, is there a nicer way? Perhaps a nested dictionary isn't actually the best way?

**UPDATES**:

1. Unfortunately I need to do this in vanilla python so using external libraries (which believe me I would love) isn't possible
2. Updated my sample code form pseudocode to actual code. Hangs head in shame.

Comment: Could you post the code you already have?

Comment: Done, apologies for eyesore.

Comment: "*Whilst this isn't wrong ... is there a nicer way?*" - Your question might be better posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, hadn't seen that before! Will go there for similar question in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is reasonable, but here is an alternative:

```
import collections
with open('grid_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    columns = next(f).split()
    matrix = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    for line in f:
        items = line.split()
        row, vals = items[0], items[1:]
        for col, val in zip(columns, vals):
            matrix[col][row] = int(val)
print(matrix)
```

which yields

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'A': {'A': 0, 'C': 6, 'B': 3}, 'C': {'A': 2, 'C': 0, 'B': 5}, 'B': {'A': 1, 'C': 7, 'B': 0}})
```

---

Some tips:

- Use

  ```
  with open(...) as f
      ...
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  f = open(...)
  f.close()
  ```

  because the [file handle is closed for you](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) when Python leaves the
  `with-block`. By using `with` you'll never forget to close a filehandle, and even if an exception occurs, the filehandle will still be closed upon leaving the `with-block`.
- Generally, it is better to avoid `f.readlines()` if you can. This
  slurps the entire file into a list. That can be onerous on memory,
  especially if the file is huge. Usually

  ```
  with open(...) as f:
      for line in f:
  ```

  can be used instead.
- If you make `matrix` a [collections.default(dict)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) then 
  `matrix[field]` will be a `dict` by default. So you can skip the
  initialization:

  ```
  for key in keys:
      matrix[key] = {}
  ```
- A `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, so you can use it very much
  as you would a `dict`. If you don't like the way it prints or would
  like to stop `matrix` from automagically assigning an empty dict to
  `matrix[key]` for any `key`, you can convert the defaultdict back to
  a regular `dict` with:

  ```
  matrix = dict(matrix)
  ```
- Avoid using numerical indices in `for-loops` if you can.

  ```
  for i, c in enumerate(chars[1:]):
  ```

  Although this is *de rigueur* for most C-like languages, Python has a
  better way: looping over the items themselves:

  ```
  for col, val in zip(columns, vals):
  ```

  This makes the code more readable, because it assigns a variable name
  to the object you are actually interested in, not just an index which
  you then have to compose into things like `keys[i-1]`. It also helps
  you avoid "off-by-one" errors which can occur when you have to adjust
  the index by one, as is done in `keys[i-1]`.

---

Another possibility is to not use nested dicts, but rather 2-tuples (column, row) as keys:

```
with open('grid_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    columns = next(f).split()
    matrix = {}
    for line in f:
        items = line.split()
        row, vals = items[0], items[1:]
        for col, val in zip(columns, vals):
            matrix[col, row] = int(val)
print(matrix)
```

yields

```
{('B', 'C'): 7, ('A', 'A'): 0, ('B', 'B'): 0, ('B', 'A'): 1, ('C', 'A'): 2, ('C', 'B'): 5, ('C', 'C'): 0, ('A', 'B'): 3, ('A', 'C'): 6}
```

Then you can access a (column, row) in the matrix like this:

```
print(matrix['A','C'])
# 6
```

---

By the way, if you install [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

text = '''\
A  B  C
A 0  1  2
B 3  0  5
C 6  7  0'''

df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(text), sep='\s+')
print(df.to_dict())
```

yields

```
{'A': {'A': 0, 'B': 3, 'C': 6},
 'B': {'A': 1, 'B': 0, 'C': 7},
 'C': {'A': 2, 'B': 5, 'C': 0}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that looks great and I just had a look at pandas as well, good shout! However, annoyingly in this case I ideally need to do it in vanilla python. Any ideas?

Comment: Fantastic answer, managed to use a few of these tricks to neaten up a bunch of other code as well. Really appreciated. I would upvote multiple times if I could. Out of interest, would there be a speed access or memory footprint impact of tuples over dicts?

Comment: I would choose the data structure based on the intended usage. If you always want to retrieve individual values given a column and a row, then `matrix[col, row]` seems a bit more readable than `matrix[col][row]` to me. There is essentially no difference in speed. (I timed the two using IPython's [%timeit command](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#magic-functions)).

Comment: There is a minor difference is the memory footprints (as measured by [pympler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pympler))-- the dict of dicts is a bit smaller than the dict with tuples as keys -- but I wouldn't worry about that (or the performance issue) unless it becomes a bottleneck.

Comment: Cheers, was just interested and it won't be a bottleneck in this code, I was just interested.